# Unique extension of a bounded linear operator : Reference request

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, operator-theory, banach-spaces

Does someone know a textbook which states the theorem considered in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2992549/there-exists-a-unique-extension-hatt-of-a-bounded-linear-operator-t)? Preferably, such a book should be released recently rather than many years ago as I'd prefer a source which does not use an ancient notation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Robert E. Megginson, *An Introduction to Banach Space Theory*, page 70.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is an exercise in Rudin's functional analysis book. Additionally, there is a result close to this that is in Kreyszig's functional analysis text. Kreyszig has the following result on pg 100 (Thm 2.7-11):

Let $T: \mathscr{D}(T) \to Y$ be a bounded linear operator, where $\mathscr{D}(T)$ lies in a normed space $X$ and $Y$ is a Banach space. Then, $T$ has an extension $\hat{T}: \overline{\mathscr{D}(T)} \to Y$ satisfying $\|\hat T\| = \|T\|$.