# Uniqueness of Hahn-Banach extension of a linear map

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, hahn-banach-theorem

Let $X,Y$ be normed vector spaces and $V \subset X$ be a non-closed subspace. Let $A : V \rightarrow Y$ be a linear map.

How can I prove that there always exists an extension of A to a linear map $\overline{V} \rightarrow Y$ and that this extension is unique iff $A$ is bounded ?

I guess one has to use Hahn-Banach extension theorem but I don't see how to proceed for the uniqueness part.

Thank you in advance for your help !

Comment: If $A$ is bounded then the extension can be defined by $A(\lim v_n):= \lim A(v_n)$ - but this needs compleness of $Y$. If $A$ is not bounded then one has to use Hamel basis.

Comment: see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2992549/there-exists-a-unique-extension-hatt-of-a-bounded-linear-operator-t

Comment: The extension **to the closure** is not a Hahn-Banach extension.  To extend a **continuous** linear map to the closure, do it by continuity, as explained by @daw . Also note that $Y$ must be assumed complete, or this will not be possible.  So, you should fix your question: Do you assume $A$ is continuous?  Do you assume $Y$ is complete?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this statement is false. If there is an extension there are infinitely many whether or not $A$ is bounded. (As stated, there is no requirement that the extended linear map is bounded, even in the case $A$ is bounded).

There  is a linear functional $f$ on $\overline V$ which is $0$ in $V$ but not on $\overline V$. Fix $y \neq 0$ in $Y$ and consider $B(.)+nf(.)y$ where $B$ is any extension of $A$ to $\overline V$. These are all distinct extension of $A$ to linear maps on $\overline V$.

Comment: @daw I don't understand. I did not consider an extension to $X$.